# Accessibility: input with image - use value-, alt- or title-attribute?

Tags: html, accessibility, submit-button, wcag, wcag2.0

I have the following input on a site I'm currently reviewing:

```
<input type="submit" name="executeSearch" value="" alt="Execute search" title="Execute search" class="iconButton searchBtn">
```

Through the class attribut the input button is replaced by an search icon.

According to accessibility is this the right way? Or should the value attribute be used? The screenreader I tested this element with (NVDA) was able to read the text ("Execute search button").

Answer (score 1):

An empty value and an icon added via CSS to convey the only important information is a failure according to WCAG 2.0: [F3 - Failure (…) due to using CSS to include images that convey important information](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/F3.html)

Simplest solution: use an `input[type="image"]`, keep that `alt="Execute search"` ("Search" would be more concise IMHO), add an `src="/path/to/img"` of course and remove both title and value attributes. Image can be an SVG and can be encoded in base64 (ideal when it's light for performance reasons: that's 1 resource *not* to be downloaded).
That `[type="image"]` *seems* outdated because it was widely used circa IE6, way before RWD but it isn't ([proof of concept with an 8x16 viewBox and width*height SVG](https://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/bvjzYr): *it scales®*)

Otherwise you can use a button element with `type="submit"`. This element can contain SVG, HTML images, text hidden to screen readers (better known as `.visually-hidden`, `.sr-only` or `.element-invisible` in Bootstrap, WordPress, Drupal, etc). That's what I use when a "submit" has both text and image or icon because no :pseudo with input and text-only through @value

Some notes on your current markup:

- `@alt` should only be used with `input[type="image"]`
- `@value` shouldn't be used with type image and otherwise should never be empty
- `@title` should only be there (on links and "buttons") if it adds something to the existing information (like Subscribe ⇒ Subscribe to the newsletter or Edit ⇒ Edit something in particular)

Comment: Worth mentioning, the `title` attribute doesn't get read by some screen readers unless the user tabs to the element (JAWS for example). If it's important information that needs to be conveyed, it's best to not use `title` as the sole method of presenting it.

Answer (score 0):

> According to accessibility is this the right way? Or should the value attribute be used?

- An `input[type='submit']` button does not accept an `alt` attribute
- Some screenreaders may use the `title` attribute, but it's still useful for non screenreader users
- Using the `value` attribute is the recommended approach for screenreader users